# Detecting a closed connection in Restlet

Tags: restlet

I have a Restlet server application that needs to do some cleanup when the response representation has been incompletely delivered (due to user hitting the stop button etc.). So far, I have found two callbacks that are called after the representation has been sent:

1. Override `OutputRepresentation.release()` in my custom representation
2. Pass a [Uniform](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.0/jse/api/org/restlet/Uniform.html) instance to `Resource.setOnSent(Uniform)`

Both of these are called whether or not the response representation has been completely delivered. How can I check whether the representation has been completely delivered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I worked around this was by discovering that Restlet will throw an IOException when the connection is broken. I can just do my cleanup in a catch block.